# How to solve for imaginary roots of a quartic that cannot be factored and has no real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, quintics

Given the equation $4x^5 + 3x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x - 11 = 0$, how do I find all complex roots? Fundamental theorem of algebra states that since this is a 5th degree polynomial, there are $5$ roots. I have used rational factor theorem to find that $(x-1)$ is a factor but this leaves me with $(x-1)(4x^4 + 7x^3 + 9x^2 + 10x + 11)$ and the quartic function has no real roots and is not factorable. How do I find the four imaginary roots for that particular quartic?

Comment: try this: http://benisrael.net/NEWTON-MONTHLY.pdf also, here: https://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=41098

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) may also be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to find numerical approximations to the four non-real  roots?

Comment: There's also a closed form solution for quartic equations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots